# camera's node name not visible in statistics

Tags: ios, scenekit

I attached a name property to my camera node. The camera is fully functional and does its job.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.name = "I am camera"
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
...
```

The documentation states the following:

> The SceneKit statistics view (see showsStatistics) also shows the
>   names of nodes with attached cameras.

So I went to viewDidLoad and wrote:

```
 sceneView.showsStatistics = true
```

However, in the simulator I only see this.[image]

Not sure what to expect, but shouldn't there be  a "I am camera" text somewhere? Where can I see the " I am camera" name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this only applies to OSX applications. You can however get the name of the active camera by grabbing your SCNView's `pointOfView` node and reading the name from it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/pointOfView

Comment: From the SCNNode class reference:
Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: All of Scenekit was introduced in iOS after 8.0, are you trying to target earlier?

Comment: Actually, I'm cruising over the whole framework to see what SceneKit can do, where are its limitations so I can tackle my actual problem later. I double checked availability of showing cameras name in statistics window and it should be available in iOS applications. Still, thanks for reply